# Eigenvectors of any arbitrary matrix is same as its adjoint.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Recently I came across Normal matrices and their properties, one of which states that their eigenvectors are the same as their adjoint and are orthogonal. I've gone across some proofs and I understand it but when I tried to prove the same using the inner product, It somehow states that the above is true for any arbitrary matrix. Can someone possibly help me point out where I'm going wrong?

Let's say A is a matrix and B is its adjoint. If x is an eigenvector of A with eigenvalue k, then,

< x | A | x > = < x | k*x > = k*< x | x >

also

< x | A | x > = < Bx | x >

hence

< B*x | x > = k*< x | x > =  < kx | x >

So, x is also an eigenvector of adjoint of A.

Comment: To conclude that $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ you must establish $\langle Bx|y\rangle=\langle kx|y\rangle$ for more than just $y=x\,.$ What set of $y$ comes to mind?

Comment: I understand that it has to be True for any arbitrary vector y that may or may not be equal to x. However if we assume y to be another eigenvector of A with eigenvalue k', then <Bx|y> = <k'x|y>. Which again says x is an eigenvector of B. So is this merely a coincidence that for these two cases, x acts as eigenvector of B as well or there's something more to it?

Comment: "Which again says x is an eigenvector of B." Can you show meticulously  every single step that gets you to this conclusion, given that you just said what you undersand?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I meant that I cannot prove the same for any arbitrary y except for y being an eigenvector of A with the steps I've mentioned in the question. However I'm confused as to why is x behaving as an eigenvector of B in the inner product when y is an eigenvector of A.

Comment: "x is behaving as an eigenvector if B in the inner product". give a precise meaning to this an show the steps that led you to make the claim that x ***is*** an ev of B.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to determine why a proof is wrong, it can be very helpful to examine a counterexample step by step. Sometimes it is hard to find a counterexample, but in this case choosing almost any random matrix will suffice.

For example, consider $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 2 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which I chose by picking a random matrix with integer eigenvalues. Then a short computation shows its (right) eigenvectors $ (1, \tfrac{-1}{2})$ and $(1, 1)$, while the eigenvectors of the conjugate transpose are $(-1, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$.

This is a counterexample to the claim that the eigenvectors of any arbitrary (square) matrix are the same as those of the conjugate transpose of that matrix. I suggest going through OP's argument with this counterexample to see where the proof goes astray.

I'll also note that the OP argument implicitly claims something slightly stronger than the question title, which is that $A^*$ has the same eigenvectors *with the same associated eigenvalues*. The counterexample
$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ has the nice property that $B$ and $B^*$ have both the same eigenvectors and the same eigenvalues, *but the eigenvalue associated with each eigenvector swaps*.

---

At the bottom, I note a couple of less important asides.

To typeset nice angle brackets, use `\langle x, y \rangle`, which looks like $\langle x, y \rangle$.

In my answer, I avoid the term *adjoint* because this is an overloaded term. What we sometimes call the "(classical) adjoint" or the "adjugate" or the "adjunct" matrix (written $\mathrm{adj}(A)$) is the transpose of the cofactor matrix of $A$. The matrix form of the *adjoint operator* is also called the "adjoint", and means the conjugate transpose matrix. Or in this answer, where everything is real-valued, it could mean just the transpose matrix. Instead of choosing a convention and sticking with it, I tend to avoid the word *adjoint* altogether unless spelling it out explicitly elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I get that the counterexample you've given clearly shows that the above proof is wrong but where in the steps it goes wrong is something I'm not understanding yet. Also, you said, "I suggest going through OP's argument with this counterexample to see where the proof goes astray."  What's OP?

Comment: OP means "Original Poster" or "Original Post" (and often both at the same time). To rephrase that sentence, I might say "I suggest going through each step in the proposed proof with this counterexample to see where the proof goes astray."